# How to delete a value in a B+ Tree?

Tags: b-tree

I need to delete 87, how do I do this, I cannot find anything that is the same issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the 87. If your algorithm requires a node to be at least half full, you need to move the 85 and the 90 in the preceding node.

Comment: it requires to be half full yes, what do you mean by moving 85? what i have done is moved 77 to 90, and then moved 62 to the right os 62 and 75 are together, and 77 and 90 are together, then I have changed 68 and 85 to be 62 and 77

Comment: Well I know another algorithm that would merge the last two nodes.